# problem with rounded corners and containers

Tags: html, css, sass, styles

I'm trying to do a container with rounded corners, basically it will have a rounded corner on the top-left of the header(red) and then it should have it on the bottom left of the view that we have....

so what it is hard for me is the following:

- the bottom border should be rounded if it is the end of the page
- the border should keep straight if it isn't the end of the page.

so what I have is the following, if you see this example, the bottom left corner is rounded because the content (yellow) is not bigger than 100% therefore we show the rounded corner and also we complete the view so the corner is stick to the bottom.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: black;
}

.header {
  height: 25px;
  margin-left: 20%;
  width: 80%;
  background: red;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

.main {
  display: block;
  height: calc(100% - 25px);
  margin-left: 20%;
  width: 80%;
  background: green;
  overflow: scroll;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.content {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    header
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

the problem is when the content is bigger than the `main` as you can see, it will always be rounded as the following example and the height of the content is larger than the `main` so it should continue the line and show the corner only if the user scrolls down

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: black;
}

.header {
  height: 25px;
  margin-left: 20%;
  width: 80%;
  background: red;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

.main {
  display: block;
  height: calc(100% - 25px);
  margin-left: 20%;
  width: 80%;
  background: green;
  overflow: scroll;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.content {
  height: 900px;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    header
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I also did some test using the rounder corner on the content, but if the content is smaller it will show the rounded corner in the wrong place.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: black;
}

.header {
  height: 25px;
  margin-left: 20%;
  width: 80%;
  background: red;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

.main {
  display: block;
  height: calc(100% - 25px);
  margin-left: 20%;
  width: 80%;
  background: green;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border: 1px solid violet;
}

.content {
  height: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    header
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I'm not the best at scss(clearly :P) so I would appreciate your help.

is there a way to achieve this with only css or should I just use javascript?

Comment: why just not make bottom corner rounded as you did with top header with CSS?

Comment: I'm doing that, the problem is that it depends a lot of the `main` and the `content`